# Perform Push Segue From a Tab View Controller

Tags: ios, tabs, segue

I have a Tab Bar Controller App, the tab bar controller is forked into several "tab" view controller, in one of the view controller I want to redirect the user to an other view controller.  I create a segue from that tab view controller to the destination view controller and given it an Identifer.  And I call "performSegueWithIdentifier" in "viewDidAppear" to redirect the user.

It works fine when the segue is "Modal", however since I want to retain the tabs, I want to call the segue through "Push".  However, once I change the segue to "Push", it is not working anymore (it does not try to go to the destination view controller).  The app did not crash on the simulator but just staying on the origin tab view controller.

Comment: I think I find the answer...

Push segue only works under Navigation controller, so I need to embed my Tab Bar Controller under a navigation controller...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Push" is a mechanism for UIViewController stacks rooted in a UINavigation controller.

You can't perform a push unless the view controller in the tab is a navigation controller.

So as an example

```
TabBar VC 

...Tab 1 -> UIViewController
...Tab 2 -> UIVIewController
...Tab 3 -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController(root)
```

Only Tab 3 could perform a push segue.